# How to execute Batch File while passing parameters from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I am trying run a batch file placed at a particular path. The file requires user inputs for which I want the parameters to be passed from Excel cells. This execution of the batch file within Excel should happen by usage of click command button.

I am new to VBA. I tried the following code, but on clicking the button nothing is happening.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

   sid = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I8").Value
   user = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I9").Value
   Password = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I10").Value
   msg = "hi"
   Shell ("CMD.EXE /c C:\Users\shashank.b03\Desktop\test_CMD.bat" & sid &" "& user &" "& password &" ")

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not too sur how to call Shell functions, but just curious - could you post a sample of what it *should* look like, if called correctly? What kind of values are `sid` and `user`? Would a working file be `"CMD.EXE /c C:\Users\shashank.b03\Desktop\test_CMD.bat"SID USER PASSWORD `? (Do you perhaps need a delimiter in there?)  For a test, add `Dim myCMD as String` then `myCMD = "CMD.EXE /c C:\Users\shashank.b03\Desktop\test_CMD.bat" & sid &" "& user &" "& password &" "` and then `debug.print myCMD` and see what the command that would be called actually looks like, and see if that's accurate.

Comment: Thanks for replying Bruce, sid, user are string based values for an oracle database server. The batch file does connect to the server and performs tasks. I want the excel to serve as the front end for the application,

Comment: Forgive us, you did not answer @BruceWayne's very important question. What should command line look like if called correctly given example cell data?

Comment: Hi Parfait, 
The Command line is supposed to start the export of database using the passed parameters. It should connect to the SQL-Plus and start exp. For basic testing of the batch file parameters what I am doing is echoing the parameters out. 
`echo off

echo enter user
set /p user=
echo %user%

echo enter password
set /p password=
echo %password%

echo enter sid
set /p sid=
echo %sid%

echo %user% %password% %sid% >> C:\users\shashank.b03\desktop\test.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example which I have tested and should work fine for you. It just calls the shell command and passes it a command string.

You can change the path where your batch file is in the string & if you don't want to show the shell window when you're running this use vbHide instead of vbNormalFocus.

You'll just have to change this a bit to put the cell values into the sid, user and password variables.

Hope this helps.

```
Dim sid As String
Dim user As String
Dim password As String

CommandString = "c:\test.bat" + " " + sid + " " + user + " " + password
Call Shell("cmd.exe /c" & CommandString, vbNormalFocus)
```

Here is a more basic example of using parameters and a batch file from shell.

Save the following as test.bat

```
set arg1=%1
echo HELLO %1!
pause
```

Put this code inside a button or some other component in excel;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sid As String
sid = "Shashank"
CommandString = "c:\test.bat" + " " + sid
Call Shell("cmd.exe /c" & CommandString, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Make sure that the path where the batch file is saved is the same as the one in commandstring.

When this is run, you'll see the string held in the variable sid is passed to the batch file and used. You should be able to get it working from here.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried this code..the problem that is happening it is calling the batch files but not passing the arguments. After opening the batch file we have to again feed the parameters

Comment: Hi Shashank, sorry to ask an obvious question but when you pass the arguments are you prefixing them with the "-" character?

Comment: No Nick, I am just a beginner in VBA scripting as of now.

Comment: I will edit my answer to show you how to get the parameter to work. :)

Comment: Thanks a Lot Nick, Actually the issue was I had " set /p " command used for parameters. It was not allowing me to pass the parameters as it expected the parameter from the user itself. 

It is working now.